# Windows Server 2008 R2: Local account users can log into server without using ".\"

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain, login

We have a small, standard Windows domain, two DCs with a couple of member servers. On our 2008 R2 member servers, local admin accounts can log into the machines WITHOUT having to put the ".\" in front of the account name. Also, when the user types their local account name into the "User name" field without the ".\" in front, the text next to "log on to:" will change from the domain name to the machine/host name.

Can someone please explain to me why this happening or where the setting in the server is for this? I thought that if you wanted to log in locally to a member server, you have to put the ".\" in front of your user name, but if you want to log in with a domain account, you can just simply type in your user name.